# JavaScript error: Uncaught TypeError: a[b] is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, webforms, telerik

In my C# Webforms project I have a `RadDatePicker` control set to run a `JavaScript` function. Each time I select a date, I get this Javascript error:

> Uncaught TypeError: a[b] is not a function

Here is my code.  The JavaScript is at the top of the ASPX page that has the control

```
function SetDateSession() {
    console.log('here');
}


<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="StartDatePicker" runat="server">
    <ClientEvents OnDateSelected="SetDateSession()" />
</telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

I'm getting the error after selecting a date, and the error occurs before the console log.

I can't figure out why this very simple code doesn't work.  If I try to call the function with `onclick` from an `input` tag, it works.

```
<input type="button" id="RepBtn" onclick="SetDateSession()" value="View" runat="server"/>
```

I've simplified the code so much that it's hard for me to know what to try next.

**Answer Summary:**

Unlike HTML and ASP.NET, ***if you're using Telerik's `OnClientClicked` and passing a JavaScript function, you should not provide the parenthesis***.  Providing parenthesis will cause the function to fire on page load and NOT on click.

For example, a RadButton generates this HTML:

```
<a id="exampleBtn" class="RadButton RadButton_Office2010Silver rbSkinnedButton"
  href="javascript:void(0)">
    <input class="rbDecorated" type="submit" name="btnStandard_input" 
      id="btnStandard_input" value="Standard Button" />
    <input id="btnStandard_ClientState" name="btnStandard_ClientState"
      type="hidden" />
</a>
```

It's an input with a type submit and when you refresh the page, it'll resubmit the form, running your JavaScript function.

Comment: what framework are you using? do you have access to sourcemaps?

Comment: Check the top of the question for the latest edit.  And I know nothing about sourcemaps

Comment: I got downvoted?  Is something wrong with my question?

Comment: Don't put console output as a screenshot as it makes it impossible to use search functions to find information

Comment: @JoeW Thank you.  The I included the image for a visual representation of how the error looked in the console.  Since people seemed to not like that, I removed it.

Comment: I completely disagree with this question being closed for being "off topic".  Can't wrap my head around how this question is off topic.  haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a waste of time on such a stupid thing!  Basically this

`<ClientEvents OnDateSelected="SetDateSession()" />`

should be this

`<ClientEvents OnDateSelected="SetDateSession" />`

Lesson learned, Telerik!  Thank you.